# MediaRecorder Start Failed Error

Tags: java, android, android-mediarecorder, android-8.0-oreo, call-recording

I want to recording a call voice but i get MediaRecorder:start failed : -2147483648

It's my call record code block

```
   public void SesKayitBaslat(String number) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "ANSWERED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String out = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
        File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/ASesKaydi");
        if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
            sampleDir.mkdirs();
        }
        String file_name = "Record";
        try {
            audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".amr", sampleDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

        recorder  = new MediaRecorder();
                          //recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);

        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e("Eror","1");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Eror","2");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(!recordstarted)
        {

            recorder.start();
            recordstarted = true;
        }
        Log.e("Kayit:", "Başladı");

    }
```

What is my error ? Can anyone help me ? I Tried  MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL AND MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION 
When i used Voice_Communication type i didn't get voice of caller.

Comment: Are you executing this code in BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: Yes sir @sagar  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code `2147483648` refers to MEDIA_ERROR_SYSTEM (low-level system error).

Based on the documentation:

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call
>   to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this
>   function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer
>   active.

In other words, the MediaRecorder instance that you expect to be there might actually not exist anymore since you're within a different BroadcastReceiver instance than the one that created the MediaRecorder. Its not a great idea to perform this task in BroadcastReceiver since it will only execute for 10 seconds after which System could declare app as not responding.

One solution would be to execute this code to `Service`